# create a dataframe with random numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

i am new to R.
i want a data frame of 8 columns with random numbers like:-

```
V1  V2   V3..... V8
 1  101  1        1
 2  102  0        1
 3  103  0        1
 .   .   .        .
 .   .   .        .
 .   .   .        .
 .   .   .        .
100 200  1        0
```

V3-V8 are columns containing sequence of 1 and 0 only.

Comment: Give `?sample` a look from the R console and then make separate vectors of random numbers of equal length.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
n <- 100 ; m <- 200 ; reps <- 6 
as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(m), n, m/n), 
                    replicate(reps, sample(c(0, 1), n, replace = TRUE))))
#      V1  V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
# 1     1 101  0  1  1  0  0  0
# 2     2 102  1  1  1  0  0  1
# 3     3 103  0  0  0  1  1  1
# 4     4 104  1  1  0  1  1  0
# ...
```

Where `n` is number of rows. `m` is the number you want to `seq_len` in your first columns. `reps` is the number of columns you want to add with random numbers between 0 and 1

Answer (score 2):

Another variation of @David Arenburg's solution

```
 as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(n*n1), ncol=n1),
      matrix(sample(0:1, n*reps, replace=TRUE), ncol=reps)))
```

where,

```
 n <- 100; reps <- 6; n1 <- 2
```

`n` is the number of rows, `reps` is the number of columns with random numbers, `n1` is the number of initial columns

Answer (score 1):

That's easy :

- Choose the number of observation N = 100
- Sample in a standard normal using `rnorm`
- Sample a number between 1 and 10 using `sample`
- Sample a character with `sample`
- Sample in a uniform distribution using `runif` and generate a binary variable using `1*(runif(N) < p)`

Here is the code :

```
N  <- 100
df  <- data.frame(id = 1:N, x1 = rnorm(N), x2 = sample(1:10, size = N, replace = TRUE), x3 = sample(letters[1:10], size = N, replace = TRUE), x4 = 1*(runif(n = N) < .75))
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg sure. I've made the clarification.