# Applying Counter in data.table lapply function

Tags: r, data.table

I want to track how `lapply` processes columns in `data.table`. I generally do this when reading large number of files, but I was thinking whether I can also do this for columns operations. Specifically, let's say I want to replace `NA` using `locf()` method, and want to see the status as every variable is processed.

What I have noticed is that `data.table` first prints the output of the counter and then starts processing.

Here's test code:

```
  n <- 100000
  reps <- 20
  n1 <- 20

  df <- data.table::as.data.table(as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(n*n1), ncol=n1),
                      matrix(sample(0:1, n*reps, replace=TRUE), ncol=reps))))

  #Randomly insert NAs 
  df <- data.table::as.data.table(lapply(df, function(cc) 
    cc[sample(c(TRUE, NA), prob = c(0.85, 0.15), size = length(cc), replace = TRUE) ]))
  df$V1 <- c(1:n)
  data.table::setDT(df)

  counter <- 0
  cols <- colnames(df)

  df[, (cols):=lapply(.SD, function(x) {
    counter <<- counter + 1
    y <- na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm=FALSE)

    if(counter %in% round(seq(from = 0, to = length(cols), length.out=35))) {
      print(paste(round(counter/length(cols)*100,digits = 2),
                  "% has been processed;", counter, "columns"))
    }
    y
  }), by = V1, .SDcols = cols]
```

(I have stolen random dataframe generation from akrun's response in [create a dataframe with random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26119054/create-a-dataframe-with-random-numbers).)

Here's what happens upon executing the code:

R first prints:

```
[1] "2.5 % has been processed; 1 columns"
[1] "5 % has been processed; 2 columns"
[1] "10 % has been processed; 4 columns"
[1] "12.5 % has been processed; 5 columns"
[1] "15 % has been processed; 6 columns"
...
[1] "97.5 % has been processed; 39 columns"
[1] "100 % has been processed; 40 columns"
```

and then it starts processing, which is counter-intuitive. Is there any way I can track the columns as they are processed?

Comment: If your cols are all of the same class, you can `melt` it into long form, in which case tracking status by `by=` group is simple.

Comment: @Frank - Thanks, but my columns may not necessarily be of the same class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is caused by row-wise grouping.

This works for me:

```
library(data.table)
counter <- 0
df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  counter <<- counter + 1
  cat(counter, " ", length(x), " ")
  cat(sum(is.na(x)), " ")
  y <- zoo::na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE, na.rm = FALSE)
  cat(sum(is.na(y)), "\n")
  return(y)
}), .SDcols = cols]
#1  14967  1 
#2  14911  0 
#3  14740  0 
#...
#38  14928  0 
#39  15090  1 
#40  14811  0
```

Note that I have removed the `by = V1` because row-wise processing was awfully slow. Your version with `by = V1` took 2.41 sec for only 1000 (!) rows while the version *without* row-wise `by` took 0.44 for 100 000 rows. That is a speed-up of roughly of 600 times.

BTW: `na.locf()` won't work as expected with row-wise grouping.

To make sure that `counter` is printed *during* computation , I've printed the number of `NA` elements before and after the call to `na.locf()`.

In response to [this comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617291/applying-counter-in-data-table-lapply-function/42624935#comment72380211_42624935) and [my reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617291/applying-counter-in-data-table-lapply-function/42624935#comment72381059_42624935), I've modified the first `cat()` statement to print also the length of `x` in order to demonstrate the crucial effect of row-wise grouping `by = V1`.

Comment: Thanks Uwe! I have one follow-up question: do you mind explaining what you mean by `na.locf() won't work as expected with row-wise grouping`?

Comment: _Without_ `by = V1`, `na.locf(x, fromLast = TRUE, ...)` takes one complete column vector and replaces missing values from the next non-NA value further down the column. So, `c(NA, NA, 1, 2)` becomes `c(1, 1, 1, 2)`. _With_  `by = V1` and `V1` a row number,  the `data.table` is processed row-wise`. So, `na.locf()` will only get one element of the column vector after the other, e.g. `c(NA)`. So it has no replacement value. You can double check if you print the length of `x`.

Comment: thanks. I am curious--do you think we can print counters, assuming that we want `by` i.e. row-wise processing? I'm curious.

Comment: Yes, this will work, just modify above code by adding `by = V1`. However, why should you want to do row-wise processing, especially with large data.tables, unless there is a really good reason? You will loose most of `data.table`'s performance benefits. So, let's put it the other way around: What is the underlying problem that you want to solve?

Comment: Thank you...The challenge is that `V1` is the `key`. While I was trying to create a sample example that has a large `data.frame`, I unintentionally forgot that there are groupings in my `V1` i.e. `V1` shouldn't be `1:n` but something like `1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2...` etc. You are absolutely correct in that if `V1 = 1:n`, there is no point in grouping it. This was a mistake on my part. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Uwe - I have another question, if you don't mind. Why is it that `print` doesn't work, but `cat` does? It's quite strange. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: `print()` does work for me as well as `cat()` in my code snippet. Not sure what the problem is for you. If this is something of major concern to you I suggest to ask a new question including a [mcve] and the code which doesn't work to your expectations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137362/discussion-between-uwe-block-and-watchtower).